# Rivendell on Ubuntu

Tags: internet-radio

Ive just joined this group and need some help on installing Rivendell automation software for our community radio station. Does anyone know of any download links please?

Comment: have you looked at this resource: https://tecwhisperer.com/install-rivendell-automation-part-1-system-preparation/

Comment: [http://www.rivendellaudio.org/](http://www.rivendellaudio.org/) I hope the link above may be what you're after. The software is available as either source code or pre-compiled, from what I can see.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be a package available in the repositories, however, there's a github project [here](https://github.com/ElvishArtisan/rivendell) that as of this moment was last updated 10/9/2019 and the [INSTALL file](https://github.com/ElvishArtisan/rivendell/blob/master/INSTALL) mentions all the necessary prerequisites to [build it.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123077/installing-applications-from-source)

In case you are unfamiliar a prerequisite is something required that must exist on your system prior to installing. You can find answers on how to [clone the project on your system here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802239/how-to-clone-a-git-repository/802243)

Be aware that while http://www.rivendellaudio.org/ lists SuSE Linux Professional 9.x as a recommended system requirement, since Ubuntu is also a distribution of 
GNU/Linux you should be able to do this successfully.

You can confirm that you have git installed with the command and response shown below.

```
$ which git
 /usr/bin/git
```

If `which` doesn't show it's already installed you can obtain it with `sudo apt install git`

Sources:

https://tecwhisperer.com/install-rivendell-automation-part-1-system-preparation/

https://github.com/ElvishArtisan/rivendell

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=rivendell&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

[Installing applications from source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123077/installing-applications-from-source)

There's also a slightly older source rivendell-3.1.0.tar.gz last updated September 19th 2019 (as of this writing) at http://www.rivendellaudio.org/ftpdocs/rivendell/